# Dropdown Error State for Quiz

Tags: responsive-design, dropdown, quiz

I need a little help with this one. We are creating a quiz that has drop down inputs for many of the questions. Essentially, the user would select an answer from the dropdown and than click submit.

On event submit the answer is checked, if it is wrong, the correct answer is displayed by its side. Issue is that the drop down text has no character limits, so some answers could be entire sentences. We are having issues figuring out the best way to display the correct answer alongside the incorrect answer for the dropdown input.

This design also has to be responsive and adhere to accessibility requirements.

Here's what we came up with. As you can see the paragraph shifts to make room for the correct answers. We were concern that this shift would be jarring for users. Would like any other thoughts or variations. Thanks!

[image: Dropdown Question]

Comment: it would be more intuitive with radio buttons, as that how most pages online do this kind of things*, I have never seen this with dropdowns. I know im not helpful but just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you broke up the paragraph? Keep the sentences in order but allow enough space for an answer between them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I look your design from a teachers paper correction behavior.The most common connection is circling the wrong answer and writing  the right one on top. This would distort the current paragraph view as you need extra space in line height or beside the blank. The simple one I can come out now is giving a correction space  below once I want to check my answer.

[image]

I find your solution good enough if distortion is not an issue here.

Comment: Hi Rajib, seems to me that a lot of the other examples online also show the correct answer below the question. This might be a feasible way without causing the user to scroll back and forth to compare their answer to the right answer. However, I still think its difficult to read the entire paragraph and compare the paragraph to the right answers on a mobile device.